# Hover line with auto width is under items menus

Tags: css, menu, hover

Need your help.
I have items menu and bottom line with auto width, depending on the menu item.

http://jsfiddle.net/wS45c/ - this red line must be inside grey hover. How to do?
Box-shadow don't help:(

```
HTML
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Price</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

CSS 

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    vetical-align: top;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu a:hover {
    background: #242424;
    box-shadow: 0 25px 0 -20px red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this line :

```
box-shadow: 0 25px 0 -20px red;
```

To:

```
box-shadow: 0px -5px 0px 0px red inset;
```

and it will work. checkout this fiddle : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/wS45c/1/)

Comment: but red line must have width name menu "Home", "Information".
Not entire width.

Comment: You have given `padding: 30px 20px;` to the `.menu a`, in this case there will be 20px padding on both left and right side. Now if you want to set the red line width to the text width then it may not be possible with the css, You can give like `padding:30px 0;` and `margin:0 20px;` but this will affect the background gray color. You can use jQuery with css for this effect.